# Undefined offset: 2 in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to keep the values in multiselect however, it shows Undefined offset: 2. The codes is below for the blade file.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="warehouseId[]" id="warehouse" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
@if($warehouseData)
  @foreach ($warehouseData as $key => $warehouse)
    <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}" >{{$warehouse->name}} {{$adminUserWarehouseSelectedData[$key]->id}}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
</select>
```

Comment: where do you get the error? In JS or Lraravel show that code too.

Comment: in Laravel, I got this error

Comment: it's simple, undefined index  for adminUserWarehouseSelectedData

Comment: add the controller code...

Comment: in your controller, right before returning view, add "dd($adminUserWarehouseSelectedData)" and see if it has index 2. I'm 99% sure it doesn't, so you can look for your logic error

Comment: Share value of `adminUserWarehouseSelectedData` ?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara As this question's accepted answer is not 100% correct. Please tick mark my answer as accepted otherwise other stack users will get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `@isset` directive

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="warehouseId[]" id="warehouse" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
   @if($warehouseData)
      @foreach ($warehouseData as $key => $warehouse)
         @isset($adminUserWarehouseSelectedData[$key]->id)
           <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}">
            {{$warehouse->name}} {{$adminUserWarehouseSelectedData[$key]->id}}
           </option>
         @endisset
      @endforeach
  @endif
</select>
```

Comment: Well mistake could be in logic and in that case it should be solved not just hidden

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I agree. it's the first step for her to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you have accepted here is not 100% right. You have multiple data in `$adminUserWarehouseSelectedData` coming from controllers. As you have used **multiple select** here I assumed that.

So this is the proper way to do it.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="warehouseId[]" id="warehouse" class="form-control" style="width:100%;">
@if($warehouseData)
  @foreach ($warehouseData as $key => $warehouse)
    <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}" >{{$warehouse->name}} @foreach($adminUserWarehouseSelectedData as $data) $data->id  @endforeach {{$warehouse->name}}</option>
            @endforeach</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
</select>
```

> I know that you are not using this code but for **other users** correct answer is the most preferable answer.