# Laravel 5 Undefined offset: 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my laravel blade file, I have a multiselect box and the values are coming from the database / controller. Below are the values:

> [{"id":1,"name":"United States"},{"id":2,"name":"United
>   Kingdom"},{"id":3,"name":"China"}]

I wanted to show the values in the multiselect box as well as the already selected values by the user (that's are coming from the controller in another variable), see below;

> [{"id":2,"name":"United Kingdom"}]

Below is the code for the multi select box:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="warehouseId[]" id="warehouse" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required>
    @if($warehouseData)
        @foreach ($warehouseData as $key => $warehouse)
            <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}" @if($adminUserWarehouseSelectedData[$key]->name == $warehouse->name) Selected @endif>{{$warehouse->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

But it ended up with an error -

> Undefined offset: 1

Comment: post your complete error stack

Comment: Which data `$adminUserWarehouseSelectedData` conatins? Please show those data.

Comment: please provide the controller code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined offset: 2 in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273376/undefined-offset-2-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @ChiragPatel - [{"id":2,"name":"United Kingdom"}]

Comment: Give try to my answer. Hope it will work for you. @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="warehouseId[]" id="warehouse" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" required>
    @if($warehouseData)
        @foreach ($warehouseData as $warehouse)
            <option value="{{$warehouse->id}}"   @foreach($adminUserWarehouseSelectedData as $data) @if($data->name == $warehouse->name) Selected @endif @endforeach>{{$warehouse->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

Error was there because `$adminUserWarehouseSelectedData` this variable contains multiple data and we were trying to take it as a single data.
So you have to do foreach loop for that.

Comment: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.